# How to install ubuntu 16.04 on xps 15 9560?

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, dell, xps

Does anyone has any experience on doing that? I follow the "install ubuntu" part in this article: https://github.com/rcasero/doc/wiki/Ubuntu-linux-on-Dell-XPS-15-(9560)

I am able to make a bootable usb.

When I press the install ubuntu icon on desktop, I am always redirect back to login screen. Sometimes, if I am luck, I am able to by pass it and get into the installation steps, but in the middle of installation, it will crash.

Any idea?

Comment: I installed Ubuntu 16.04, dual booting with windows,  on this machine yesterday, following the same instructions. I didn't see the issue you are getting. Perhaps try remaking the bootable ubuntu usb?

Comment: I have tried 20+ times. Still not working. Also try ubuntu 16.10, 17.04, linux mint 18. The UI will crash during half way. Also try unetbooting, same result.

Comment: I didn't follow the instructions exactly, as when I did the installation it wouldn't show me the "install beside windows" option until I had freed up some space for the linux partition. To do this I used gparted, which is on the live version of Ubuntu and shrunk the windows partition, leaving the freed space as unallocated. Although you are seeing something different, maybe that is worth a shot....